# Python long idle connection in cx_Oracle getting: DPI-1080: connection was closed by ORA-3113

Tags: python, oracle, networking, cx-oracle

I have long-running Python executable running.
Open Oracle connection using cx_Oracle on start.
After more than 45-60 mins of idle connects - it get's this error.
Any idea or special setup required in cx_Oracle ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of leaving a connection unused in your application, consider closing it when it isn't needed, and then reopening when it is needed.  Using a connection pool would be recommended, since pools can handle some underlying failures such as yours and will give you a usable connection.

At application initialization start the pool once:

```
pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user="username", password=pw, 
                  dsn="localhost/orclpdb1", min=0, max=4, increment=1)
```

Then later get the connection and hold it only when you need it:

```
with pool.acquire() as connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for result in cursor.execute(
             """select sys_context('userenv','sid') from dual"""):
        print(result)
```

The end of the `with` block will release the connection back to the pool.  It
won't be closed.  The next time `acquire()` is called the pool can check the
connection is still usable.  If it isn't, it will give you a new one.  Because of these checks, the pool is useful even if you only have one connection.

See my blog post [Always Use Connection Pools — and
How](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/always-use-connection-pools-and-how-909bc2c65444)
most of which applies to cx_Oracle.

But if you don't want to change your code, then try setting an Oracle Network parameter [`EXPIRE_TIME`](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-1070805B-0703-457C-8D2E-4EEC26193E5F) as shown in the [cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html#network-configuration) and [python-oracledb documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html#network-configuration).  This can be set in various places. In C-based Oracle clients like cx_Oracle and the Thick mode of [python-oracledb](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a):

- With 18c client libraries it can be added as `(EXPIRE_TIME=n)` to the DESCRIPTION section of a connect descriptor
- With 19c client libraries it can additionally be used via Easy Connect: `host/service?expire_time=n`.
- With 21c client libraries it can additionally be used in a client-side sqlnet.ora file

If EXPIRE_TIME is used to prevent firewalls terminating idle
connections, then the value should be just less than half of the firewall timeout period.

With the Thin mode of python-oracledb you can pass an `expire_time` parameter when you create a connection or pool, for example:

```
pool = oracledb.create_pool(user="username", password=pw, 
                            dsn="dbhost.example.com/orclpdb",
                            min=0, max=4, increment=1
                            expire_time=4)
```

This may not always help, depending what is closing the connection.

Fundamentally you should/could fix the root cause, which could be a firewall timeout, or a DBA-imposed user resource or DB idle time limit.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer  - insightful !